# Fetch returns empty JSON after POST request

Tags: express, fetch

I'm using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send `POST` request to my Express server, but I always get empty JSON (`{}`) instead of the data I have sent.

```
var postData = function (url, data) {
    return fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        return data;
    });
};

var firstField = document.querySelector('#first-field').value;
var secondField = document.querySelector('#second-field').value;

if (firstField.trim().length && secondField.trim().length) {
    postData('http://localhost:3000/test', { x: firstField, y: secondField })
    .then(function (data) { console.log(data) })
    .catch(function (error) { console.error(error) });
}
```

Here is the Express route:

```
app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    const x = req.body.x;
    const y = req.body.y;

    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        x: x,
        y: y
    }));
});
```

Comment: do you have the bodyparser middleware set up? also, instead of doing `res.send(JSON.stringify`, you can just do `res.json`

Comment: @JSilv, yes, I have it.

Answer (score 1):

spend the good amount of yesterday figuring this out.

You can solve it by installing cors middleware to express.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
npm install cors
```

and add it to your app. before the body-parsers.

```
app.use( cors() )
app.use( bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) )
```

This should fix the empty body express is returning with Fetch API. Apparently using jQuery ajax post request works out of the box. Haven't investigating further why.

Good Luck.

/S